# How to update a field of a particular row in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-list

I just wanted update a particular field not the entire row of the list, is there any way to do it by using the rest API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function, with only setting that one field in the json.

```
// Update item
// item = { __metadata: {type: SP.Data.xxxListItem }, ....} 
UpdateListItem = function (listName, itemId, item) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: encodeURI(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")"),
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        }
    });
}
```

So:

```
var item =  { __metadata: {type: SP.Data.MyListNameListItem }, FieldToChange: "test"}
UpdateListItem("MyListName", 10, item)
```

Answer (score 1):

In RestApi there is method called Merge which take your current data and merge i.e update it with new data. Below function helps to solve your question.

```
function UpdateListItem(listName,myID)
    {

        var valToUpdate = "abcde";              

        var item = {
            "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
            "listItem": valToUpdate,

        };

        $.ajax({
            url:  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl  + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + myID + ")",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

> "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE" it will update our new value to the old value later.Finally, as our task here is to update data in SharePoint entity (list in this case), the operation is of type/method – “POST”.
>   The success block alerts a “success” string, after which a page refresh takes place, and the updated data can be seen in the list item.